# Reliable software for ESC/POS thermal printer (USB interface)

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, usb, printing

I installed the printer driver, but the manufacturer didn't provide much in the way of SDK or API. They assumed that the printer will only be used with a USB printer software POS, but I want to print from the Windows and give it our own design etc. and extra logic.

How can we print say TXT, DOCX or PNG to the printer? When I try to print to the printer from Windows it doesn't print, it stays in the queue with errors and interrupted the bluetooth devices. How do you get it to work? Thanks!

Windows 10 or Windows 8 software would be great ! I don't mind to pay ...